# Palette for text styling

Tags: front-end, text, customization, style

When modifying the style of a document, such as the headings, I find it tedious to be constantly visiting the menu every time I need to change a color/style/size/etc.

Is there a palette or other easier way to change the style of text and do formatting?

Comment: Window -> Toolbar -> Formatting?  If you want to modify all headers, edit the stylesheet (Format menu).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here's an example I found in the "Creating Palettes" section in the Documentation Center that does part of what you want.

```
CreatePalette[
  Column[Button[Style[#, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
      FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "Style", #], 
      Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 120] & /@ {"Title", 
     "Subtitle", "Subsubtitle", "Section", "Subsection", 
     "Subsubsection", "Text", "Code", "Input"}, Spacings -> 0]];
```

You should be able to come up with functions similar that can answer the rest of your question.  If you want, you can use the currentvalue[] function for the button so that you always know the current state of the style, font type, font size and color.  Sometimes its nice to know this on from the get go.  I've made buttons allowing me to change numerous settings like you have suggested.  Let me know if you want more examples.